# WSO2 AM 1.10.0 site not secure in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I followed up the steps, https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon443/Creating+New+Keystores, to add CA certificate to api manager. it was working fine in Chrome until my organization updated the Chrome, and then Chrome said it is not security site any longer,
[image]

However it is still secure site in IE,
[image]

Could please anyone has idea to solve this issue?

Thanks,Bo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a WSO2 issue it is a certificate issue.  On your certificate the domain needs to be listed in the SAN (Subject Alternative Name).  Alot of people still ignore that field and use the Common Name field.  In Chrome 58 the Common Name field is now ignored and it requires certs to have the SAN properly filled in or you will see the certificate errors you are receiving.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your help. So if I add SAN to certificate, the second error will be solved as well -- common name invalid error?

Comment: We were receiving both errors and yes when we fixed the SAN error it resolved both certificate error messages for us.